# Cordova InAppBrowser not working via build.phonegap.com

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-build

I am working on an simple Phonegap App with Cordova InAppBrowser.  I am testing on my Android device.

In the config.xml I got the below code

```
....
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-5.2.0" />
.....
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" source="pgb" />
.....
<access origin="*"/>

<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />

<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="data:*" />

....
```

In Javascript I got the below code when a button is clicked

```
....
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://google.com', '_blank', 'location=yes','fullscreen=no');
....
```

index.html

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src * 'self' data:">
```

I use Phonegap Desktop App for testing purposes.  In that when the button is touched a browser window got opened and I could see the google.

But when I build the same via http://build.phonegap.com and install on my device.  Nothing opens after I touch the button.  Something goes wrong here.

Looks strange for me.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: try running the adb chrome plugin, and live inspect the view, check console message and see what may be going wrong. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adb/dpngiggdglpdnjdoaefidgiigpemgage

Comment: @mani I never used this before.. Should i download Android Studio and Tools in order to use chrome adb plugin?

Comment: you may not need to download android studio, but yes download android tools (adb), enable developer mode on your device. Debugging this way might point you in the right direction.

Comment: Can you post your index.html or at least the head portion of it, you may have a Content Security Policy issue?

Comment: have you tried with https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser ?

Comment: [Tutorial: Phonegap Build external webpage in iframe with whitelist example](https://jssnippets.wordpress.com/2016/02/16/phonegap-build-external-webpage-in-iframe-with-whitelist-example/) -- [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md) -- [HOW TO apply the Cordova/Phonegap the whitelist system](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/the-whitelist-system.md)

Answer (score 1):

I posted the same question on Adobe Forums and got the solution for my problem.

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2138992

After changing the below, it started working

```
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" source="pgb" />
```

to

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" />
```